# How to select only some values of an association based on some criteria

Tags: filtering

Here is the association I have:

```
assc = {"abc" -> 2.456, "efg" -> 3.652, "_final" -> 6.108}
```

I need to remove all key-value pairs where keys start with '_'.
I am new to Mathematica, so can anyone please help me out with this. I have a condition (mentioned below), I just don't know how to apply it on an association using 'select'?

The condition I have is:

```
(StringStartsQ[Keys[assc], "_"])

Output:= {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, \
False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True}
```

Comment: Try `Pick[assc, StringStartsQ[Keys[assc], Except["_"]]]`

Comment: Point of information: `assc = {"abc" -> 2.456, ... }` is a list of rules not an association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Select[
 assc
 , Not[
   StringStartsQ[
    Keys[#]
    , "_"
    ]
   ] &
 ]
```

### [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
DeleteCases[
 assc
 , _?(StringStartsQ[Keys[#], "_"] &)
 ]
```

### [`KeySelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeySelect.html)

Thanks to @JasonB for this solution.

```
KeySelect[
 assc
 , Not@*StringStartsQ["_"]
 ]
```

Comment: You can shorten it a bit with `KeySelect[ assc, Not@*StringStartsQ["_"]]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks! Didn't know about that one! Incorporated to the answer.

Comment: @rhermans: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately the solutions using 'Select' and 'DeleteCases' did not produce the correct result, I'm still trying on making it work.

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you! The solution worked. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Rajat Bhattacharjee Your edit was  somewhat too extensive. That's why I voted for its rejection. However, I see that you found several caveats and their resolutions. Hence, I would like to encourage you to post your edit it as a separate answer.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thats no problem. The current answers are right. At the time I wasn't getting an answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @RajatBhattacharjee Okay, fine. :)